# .npmignore not ignoring files

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a private module stored on github that I'm including in one of my projects using `npm`. The module has a `.npmignore` file, but nothing is being ignored when I install or update the module.

Project's `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "Your Cool Project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "myModule" : "git+ssh://git@github.com:user/myModule.git",
    /* All your other dependencies */
  }
  ...
}
```

Module's `.npmignore` file

```
.git*
gulpfile.js
index.html
tests.js
README.md
```

When I run `npm update myModule` these files are still being downloaded into my project. Am I missing something? Does `.npmignore` work for privately hosted modules? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is to be noted that README is always included, even if listed in `.npmignore`. See [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package)

Comment: You can use `npm publish --dry-run` to be sure what's going online.

Comment: Note that if you have a `main` property in your `package.json` and you try to ignore a directory that the path assigned to `main` is in, `npm publish` will include it. 
Idk the nuances of how this works, I just discovered it through experimenting. Doesn't seem to be documented anywhere that I've found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you're specifying the dependency `myModule` as a Git repository, npm is probably just cloning the repo.  Therefore your `.npmignore` files isn't being used.

`.npmignore` seems to be used when "making modules" eg: `pack` or `publish` not consuming modules (like in your example).

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when using `.npmignore`

If you haven't been using `.npmignore`, it defaults to `.gitignore` with a few additional sane defaults.

What many don't realize that once you add a `.npmignore` file to your project the `.gitignore` rules are (ironically) ignored. The result is you will need to audit the two ignore files in sync to prevent sensitive leaks when publishing.

Still, I think is missing put the `/node_modules` in your `.npmignore`.

Set the attribute `private: true` in `package.json` file as below:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```

Generate the build into `/public` folder to publish it to NPM repository with `.npmignore` into that folder.